# Is the Tetragrammaton YHWV or YHVH

Tags: translation, tetragrammaton

It seems to me that v is an "older" version and that the W is becoming more popular. Also I see the J/Y in much the same way.

Is there a reason that J goes with V. What about JHWH? I'm not much of a linguist so this is based off what I have read and seen.

Side note: have you heard the idea of these being the sound of breathing and not meant to have clear pronunciations. Any thoughts on that.

Comment: Everything except the last sentence is best suited on our sister site, [Biblical Hermeneutics](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/). This isn't about Christianity, per se. It is about the language of the Scriptures.

Comment: It isn't really any of those. It's יהוה. It's definitely not YHWV! But yes, this is off-topic.

Comment: As letters go, 'V' is older than 'W', since the latter didn't exist until roughly the [7th or 8th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W#History), so it would make sense that older tetragrammations would use V (or possibly VV).

Comment: It's "your" call if some thing is off topic, but then why do you have a translation AND a tetragamaton tag for this site?

Answer (score 3):

Modern Hebrew uses a 'V' sound and the letter is called *vav*.  In early, [biblical Hebrew](http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/3_waw.html), it appears that the same letter was pronounced 'W'. To avoid confusion, many (but not all) linguists refer to the letter as *waw* when used in biblical Hebrew.

So, YHVH and YHWH are both correct, but YHWH is generally preferred for biblical references.

It did have a clear pronunciation, although early Hebrew writing does not provide vowel indicators. It is beleived to have been pronounced *Yahweh*.

Incidentally, the 'J' sound comes from German. Many early biblical scholars were German, and they transliterated the Hebrew into the German language.

Comment: And you can read much more (than you want to know) about this, and the debate about pronunciation, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton#Pronunciation).